# click event prints all pages instead print range

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, events, printing

I have the following code for my BeginPrint, PrintPage and Click event. Firing the click event, its printing all pages. I would like to add a print range on button event that prints from-to range:

BeginPrint:

```
    private void printDocument1_BeginPrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
    {
        curRow = 0;
        curCopy = 0;
        if (printrange)
        {
            ((PrintDocument)sender).PrinterSettings.PrintRange = PrintRange.SomePages;
            ((PrintDocument)sender).PrinterSettings.FromPage = 1;
            ((PrintDocument)sender).PrinterSettings.ToPage = 1;
            printrange = false;
        }
    }
```

PrintPage :
I'm generating QRCodes, borders and text in this method. Usually I have more than 2 pages with QRCodes. The problem is that it prints all pages

```
    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        var curY = e.MarginBounds.Y;
        var curX = e.MarginBounds.X + 30;//+ 10
        Pen pen = new Pen(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFBD2D"), 1);

        using (var fontNormal = new Font("Arial", 10))
        using (var sf = new StringFormat())
        {
            sf.Alignment = sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            int itemHeight = (int)fontNormal.GetHeight(e.Graphics);
            

            for (int row = curRow; row < dt.Rows.Count; row++)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.Rows[row];

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr.Field<string>(1)) &&
                    int.TryParse(dr.Field<string>(4)?.ToString(), out int copies))
                {
                    for (int i = curCopy; i < copies; i++)
                    {
                        var imgRect = new Rectangle(curX, curY, 156, 156);//e.MarginBounds.X
                        var labelRect = new Rectangle(
                            imgRect.X+180+20,//eltol
                            imgRect.Bottom-162,
                            itemHeight,
                            imgRect.Width);

                        using (var qrImage = GenerateQRCODE(dr[1].ToString()))
                        {
                            e.Graphics.DrawImage(RotateImage(qrImage, -90), imgRect);
                        }

                        SizeF labelSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(dr[1].ToString(), fontNormal);

                        Bitmap stringmap = new Bitmap((int)labelSize.Height + 1, (int)labelSize.Width + 1);

                        Graphics gbitmap = Graphics.FromImage(stringmap);

                            gbitmap.TranslateTransform(0, labelSize.Width);

                            gbitmap.RotateTransform(-90);

                            gbitmap.DrawString(dr[1].ToString(), fontNormal, Brushes.Black, new PointF(0, 0), new StringFormat());

                            e.Graphics.DrawImage(stringmap, labelRect);

                        gbitmap.Dispose();
                        stringmap.Dispose();

                        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, curX, curY, curX, curY + 156);//57 |<
                        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, curX, curY + 156 , curX + 156 + 220, curY + 156);// _
                        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, curX + 156 + 220, curY + 156, curX + 156 + 220, curY);// >|
                        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, curX, curY, curX + 156 + 220, curY);// -

                        curX = imgRect.Right + 230; //horizontal gap

                        if (curX + imgRect.Width > e.MarginBounds.Right)
                        {
                            curX = e.MarginBounds.X + 30;
                            curY = labelRect.Bottom + 30;//55vertical gap
                        }

                        if (curY + imgRect.Height  >= e.MarginBounds.Bottom)
                        {
                            curCopy = i + 1;
                            e.HasMorePages = true;
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }

                curRow = row + 1;
                curCopy = 0;
            }
        }
        refreshprintbtn.Enabled = true;
        printdialogbtn.Enabled = true;
    }
```

In this click event I'm calling the print() method:

```
bool printrange = false;
private void printrangebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    printrange = true;
    printDocument1.BeginPrint += printDocument1_BeginPrint;
    printDocument1.PrintPage += printDocument1_PrintPage;
    printDocument1.Print();
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to implement the `PrintRange` part in the `PrintPage` event. Just setting the `PrintRange`, `FromPage`, and `ToPage` properties doesn't mean that the printer knows which page should start with and which one should be the last. These properties exist to get the user inputs through the print dialogs or some setter methods and you need to use them as factors in your implementation.

For example, in `PrintRange.SomePages` case, use a class field to determine the target pages to print. Increment the field and print only if the value is within the `.From` and `.To` range.

```cs
// +
System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
// ...

private int curRow, curCopy, curPage;

public YourForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    printDocument1.BeginPrint += printDocument1_BeginPrint;
    printDocument1.PrintPage += printDocument1_PrintPage;
}

private void printrangebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    printDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrintRange = PrintRange.SomePages;
    printDocument1.PrinterSettings.FromPage = 1;
    printDocument1.PrinterSettings.ToPage = 2;
    printDocument1.Print();
}

private void printDocument1_BeginPrint(object sender, PrintEventArgs e)
{
    curRow = 0;
    curCopy = 0;
    curPage = 0;
    // ...
}

private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    var curY = e.MarginBounds.Y;
    var curX = e.MarginBounds.X + 30;//+ 10
    var doc = sender as PrintDocument;

    using (var pen = new Pen(ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFBD2D")))
    using (var fontNormal = new Font("Arial", 10))
    using (var sf = new StringFormat())
    {
        sf.Alignment = sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        int itemHeight = (int)fontNormal.GetHeight(e.Graphics);

        for (int row = curRow; row < dt.Rows.Count; row++)
        {
            curPage++;

            var doPrint = doc.PrinterSettings.PrintRange != PrintRange.SomePages ||
            (curPage >= doc.PrinterSettings.FromPage && curPage <= doc.PrinterSettings.ToPage);

            DataRow dr = dt.Rows[row];

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr.Field<string>(1)) &&
                int.TryParse(dr.Field<string>(4)?.ToString(), out int copies))
            {
                for (int i = curCopy; i < copies; i++)
                {
                    var imgRect = new Rectangle(curX, curY, 156, 156);//e.MarginBounds.X
                    var labelRect = new Rectangle(
                        imgRect.X + 180 + 20,//eltol
                        imgRect.Bottom - 162,
                        itemHeight,
                        imgRect.Width);

                    // If not, don't print and continue the calculations...
                    if (doPrint)
                    {
                        using (var qrImage = GenerateQRCODE(dr[1].ToString()))
                            e.Graphics.DrawImage(RotateImage(qrImage, -90), imgRect);

                        SizeF labelSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(dr[1].ToString(), fontNormal);
                        Bitmap stringmap = new Bitmap((int)labelSize.Height + 1, (int)labelSize.Width + 1);
                        Graphics gbitmap = Graphics.FromImage(stringmap);

                        gbitmap.TranslateTransform(0, labelSize.Width);
                        gbitmap.RotateTransform(-90);
                        gbitmap.DrawString(dr[1].ToString(), fontNormal, Brushes.Black, new PointF(0, 0), new StringFormat());

                        e.Graphics.DrawImage(stringmap, labelRect);

                        gbitmap.Dispose();
                        stringmap.Dispose();

                        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, curX, curY, curX, curY + 156);//57 |<
                        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, curX, curY + 156, curX + 156 + 220, curY + 156);// _
                        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, curX + 156 + 220, curY + 156, curX + 156 + 220, curY);// >|
                        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, curX, curY, curX + 156 + 220, curY);// -
                    }

                    curX = imgRect.Right + 230; //horizontal gap

                    if (curX + imgRect.Width > e.MarginBounds.Right)
                    {
                        curX = e.MarginBounds.X + 30;
                        curY = labelRect.Bottom + 30;//55vertical gap
                    }

                    if (curY + imgRect.Height >= e.MarginBounds.Bottom)
                    {
                        if (!doPrint) break;
                        curCopy = i + 1;
                        e.HasMorePages = true;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!doPrint)
            {
                curX = e.MarginBounds.X;
                curY = e.MarginBounds.Y;
            }

            curRow = row + 1;
            curCopy = 0;
        }
    }
    refreshprintbtn.Enabled = true;
    printdialogbtn.Enabled = true;
}
```

**Side Notes**

- You shouldn't add handlers for the `PrintDocument` events each time you click a Button unless you remove the current handlers first in the `EndPrint` for example. Just add them once as shown in the Form's ctor or `Load` event.
- `System.Drawing.Pen` is a disposable object so you need to dispose of it as well. Create it with the `using` statement or pass an instance `using (pen) ...` or call the `.Dispose();` method explicitly. Do the same for any object implements the `IDisposable` interface.